# Table rows are not highlighting in Mozillafirefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla

I am designing a webpage which consists of 2 tables in it, i have given highlighting to table row when the user forget to answer it should highlight the particular row but its working for only chrome but not on Mozilla and IE

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/epeu8kcz/

Comment: Please explain the problem in detail and post the relevant code.

Comment: the table rows are not highlighting  in Mozilla and IE , i have sued java script to validate .

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: It seems you want to highlight the whole row, and and for getting'em highlighted you're targeting `<tr>`, try  targeting `<td>` that will do the trick for you, using property `border-collapse: collapse` for `<table>`.